# dotansimha angularjs-dropdown-multiselect append to body option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, multi-select

https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

Is there a way to append this to the body of the page? This is useful for situations where the multiselect list is inside of a container or other element and subsequently gets cut off.